# Ошибка в запросе - "ORA-00942: таблица или представление пользователя не существует"

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Есть запрос:

```
with eq as
 (select pe.equipment_id as id,
         row_number() over(order by pe.equipment_id) as rn
    from metrology.protocol_equipment pe
   where pe.protocol_id = :protocol_id
     and pe.pr_eq_type = 1)
select (select (select asu_tp_iis_system_id from metrology.v_equipment_info e where e.id = eq.id) from eq where rn = 1) as asu_tp_iis_system_id,
       (select (select (select d.short_name from metrology.department d where d.id = e.department_id) from metrology.equipment e where e.id = eq.id) from eq where rn = 1) as department_name,
       (select metrology.pkg_equipment.GetEquipmentDocs(eq.id, 1, 0, 1) from eq where rn = 1) as control_doc,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'ïîâåðêè', 2, 'êàëèáðîâêè') as dic_control_type,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'Ïîâåðêà', 2, 'Êàëèáðîâêà') as dic_control_type1,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'ïîâåðêå', 2, 'êàëèáðîâêå') as dic_control_type2,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'Ïîâåðêó âûïîëíèë', 2, 'Êàëèáðîâêó âûïîëíèë') as dic_control_type3,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'ïðèãîäíîñòè ÒC ' , 2, 'ñîîòâåòñòâèè äåéñòâèòåëüíûõ çíà÷åíèé ÒC òðåáîâàíèÿì ÍÄ') as dic_control_type4,
       case when p.control_type in (1,2,4,5) then 'ïåðâè÷íîé'
            when p.control_type = 3 then 'ïåðèîäè÷åñêîé'
            else ''
       end as control_type,
       doc.doc_num,
       doc.doc_date,
       metrology.utl_system.DateToChar(doc.doc_date) as doc_date_char,
       p.metrology_user_id,
       (select visual_inspection from EQUIPMENT_DOCUMENT_INFORMATION where rownum = 1) as visual_inspection,
       (select assaying from equipment_document_information where rownum = 1) as assaying,
       (select metrology.pkg_dics.GetCompanyName('long') from dual) as long_company_name,
       (select metrology.pkg_equipment.GetEquipmentDocsCode(eq.id, 1, 0, 1) from eq where rn = 1) as control_doc_code,
       (select metrology.pkg_dics.GetCompanyName('short') from dual) as short_company_name
  from metrology.protocol p 
  join metrology.doc on doc.id = p.doc_id
 where p.doc_id = :protocol_id
```

При этом, в строках:

```
(select visual_inspection from EQUIPMENT_DOCUMENT_INFORMATION where rownum = 1) as visual_inspection,
       (select assaying from equipment_document_information where rownum = 1) as assaying,
```

выдаёт ошибку:

> ORA-00942: таблица или представление пользователя не существует

Нужные права выдал, таблица существует и отчасти (напр. в процедурах) функционирует.

В чем заключается моя ошибка?

Comment: У вас в других запросах указана схема для таблиц, например `metrology.v_equipment_info`. Предполагаю, что тут тоже надо указать схему

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало)

Comment: А зачем вы этими подзапросами получаете одну _случайную_ запись ? так и задумано или вы что то напутали с rownum=1 и там должны быть еще какие то условия... И зачем вам два обращения к этой таблице, уж лучше подзапрос на выбор этой одной записи написать в from (или join сделать) и спокойно получить оба поля сразу

Answer (score 3):

> таблица существует и отчасти (напр. в процедурах) функционирует.

Частое заблуждение с ошибкой `ORA-00942`: "Но в процедуре же запрос работает".

По умолчанию процедуры и функции выполняются с правами того, кто их создал (`AUTHID DEFINER`), а не того, кто их вызывал.

Допустим, есть такая функция:

```
create or replace function getDepartmentName (id number) return varchar2
    name varchar2 (32); 
begin 
    select department_name into name 
    from departments
    where department_id = id;
    return name;
end;    
/
```

Она работает, но если попробовать выполнить тот же запрос, что и в функции:

```
select getDepartmentName (10) name from dual
/
NAME   
---------------
Administration

select * from departments where depaartment_id = 10
/
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Функция создана в другой схеме, всем даны `EXECUTE` права и создан синоним, чтобы её можно было вызывать без имени схемы. Все запросы в функции выполняются с правами её владельца:

```
select owner, object_name, object_type, authid 
from all_procedures  
where object_name = upper ('getDepartmentName')
/
OWNER OBJECT_NAME        OBJECT_TYPE  AUTHID  
----- ------------------ ------------ --------
HR    GETDEPARTMENTNAME  FUNCTION     DEFINER
```